# Rails direct upload with different buckets per model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, stimulusjs

My Rails direct upload with Stimilus Js is working fine, but now I have setup different bucket per model using service eg `has_one_attached :avatar, dependent: :purge_later, service: :avatar` and now I am getting error 422 `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Service name can't be blank):` when using JS for direct upload. It service works fine with service side upload but not working with JS(direct upload)

Is it possible to have different service setup if I am doing direct upload ? any way to pass different bucket per model when using DirectUpload ? Example will be great.